# IFrame not rendered in JSF if using external URL

Tags: jsf, iframe

When I use IFrame inside a JSF page that refering to external web page. the page isn't rendered.

JSF Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<f:loadBundle basename="resources.application" var="msg" />
<h:head>
<title>E-Payment Gateway</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/main_style.css" />

</h:head>

<h:body>
<f:view>
     <div style="height: 200px;">

    </div> 
    <div class="centercol" style="margin: auto;position: relative">
        <iframe
            src="http://google.com">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</f:view>
</h:body>
```

the HTML Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

<title>E-Payment Gateway</title>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/EPG_WEB_CUST/resources/css/main_style.css" /></head><body>
     <div style="height: 200px;">

    </div> 
    <div class="centercol" style="margin: auto;position: relative">
        <iframe src="http://google.com">
 #document<html><head></head><body></body></html></iframe>
    </div></body></html>
```

I don't know what causes this problem, It always display empty renedered HTML

Comment: non JSF, vanilla HTML markup is skipped during JSF processing. It's just passed through.

Comment: Another thought: Vodafone? Are you behind a corporate firewall which strips iFrames? Is your browser throttled?

Comment: The IT Admin is not here now, how can i make sure it is firewall problem . Thx for concerning

Comment: To see if the iFrame is being stripped: Try Googling for an iFrame tutorial site, and see if the iFrame loads.

Comment: To see if the browser is throttled: Download another browser and try loading a site known to contain iFrames.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not with JSF or firewall.

Your trying to use `http://google.com` inside an iFrame which is in different domain. This is a potential security threat, it is called Cross Site Scripting(XSS). The answer for your problem lies in the http header of google.

In order to avoid XSS attack, google has added the following headers.

```
X-FRAME-OPTIONS
X-XSS-PROTECTION
```

In other words because of the above headers you cannot access them inside an iFrame which is in different domain, learn more about XSS [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) and about Same Origin Policy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

[image]

Hope this solves your problem.