# Integrate JSF page in 3party page

Tags: html, jsf

I want to do the following:

a) I have a third party page: [https://www.example.com][1]

b) I have a JSF application: [https://www.myapplication.net][2]

```
My JSF application has also a customer portal and individual HTML forms. 

I want to have now to integration processes in the 3 party page

a) Customer Portal:

This customer portal I would like to integrate in the a) 3 party page. 
Example: User will open: [https://www.customerportal.example.org/][3]
-> The user is still his own page, but the content is from the application page.
-> My application has many users, so therefore I need a ID from the customerPortal page.
E.g. `ID = 123456789` belongs to user1 from my application. 
An idea would be to have a code snippet in the 3 party page to get an iframe.

b) Individual form:

The user from the 3 party page can send an individual url to his customer. Afterwards the HTML code will be showing in this page, but the content for this page is from my app.

Example:
User will send [https://www.example.com/form/123456789][4]
-> 123456789 is the ID from the FORM which I have in my database
-> Will call a Web service and will return the HTML from my application.

Any ideas how I can do this?


  [1]: https://www.example.com
  [2]: https://www.myapplication.net
  [3]: https://www.customerportal.example.org/
  [4]: https://www.example.com/form/123456789
```

Comment: Your question is unclear in both content and formatting. Can you improve both?

Comment: if i understand this right then you want to show content from one website in another?

Comment: Yes, correct.... I can use <iframe>... but iframe is blocked sometimes as far as I know. Furthermore how can I a get the parameter (123456789) from https://www.example.com/form/123456789 to my application?

Comment: see how to correctly add a `iframe` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933216/iframe-not-rendered-in-jsf-if-using-external-url/23825140)) and you have `<iframe src="#{someBean.url} />` the just get the last part of that string

Comment: ok, but how can I transfer 123456789 to my application? example.com/form/123456789 ... how can I got the parameter from 3party page to my application?

Comment: Effectively you ask a pure html/javascript question if you want to integrate on the client/html side. Nothing jsf related then.

Comment: No, I want to integrate my JSF page